# Regex to match integer without leading zero (s)

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this regex to match integers

```
var reg = /^\d+$/;
```

I also want it ensure that 1 or more zeros are not placed at the front

```
var reg = ^[0\d]\d+$
```

This is what I have so far but doesnt work.

How can this be done?

Passing tests

```
1
12
1232164
```

Failing tests

```
0
01
00004241
fbhf
""
a123
```

Comment: 01 should pass? can't understand what you need to match

Comment: I want to match a integer that doesnt start with 1 or more zeros @X-Pippes

Comment: I think you want: var reg = ^[1-9]\d+$

Comment: Thanks Jeanne, please add a answer :)

Comment: @Jeanne put `\d*` instead of `\d+`, otherwise your regex don't accept only one digit.

Comment: @ojhawkins added.  I didn't think a one liner was worthy of being answers.

Comment: Haha, that was all I was after :) @JeanneBoyarsky

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you want:

```
var reg = "^[1-9]\d*$";
```

If you have to match an empty string, you are best off checking for empty string before running the reg exp. Otherwise, you could do it in this harder to read regex:

```
var reg = "^(|[1-9]\d*)$";
```

It checks for an empty string or one or more digits beginning with zero.

Comment: How could I also match an empty string with this? @Jeanne Boyarsky

Comment: Just add a question mark to make the first digit optional.  I've edited that in.

Comment: The added question mark made the pattern match numbers with leading zeros again. Better check for empty string before applying the regex, or use `^([1-9]\d*)?$`.

Comment: @reima good point. doing that part without the reg exp is better. It is possible to do in one line, but harder to read.

Comment: how about more complete answers? it wont work `.value.replace(/^(|[1-9]\d*)$/g,'');` but this would work but with leading zero `.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'');`. I have no idea if '/ /g' is JS specific group? Full JQuery example would be great! Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

try this regex

```
[1-9]+[0-9]*
```

this will make you have a number that not start with zero

Comment: Matches `a123` @X-Pippes

Comment: no, don't match a123.
only acepts numbers, and can not start with 0

Comment: Hmm when I use this tool  http://regexpal.com/, is matches `a123`. Can you double check this?

Comment: matches only 123 from a123.
if you want to NOT match substring, add `^` in the beggining
`^[1-9]+[0-9]*`

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

0*([1-9][0-9]*|0)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.